# PhpUnit: How to check check order of chosen array elements

Tags: arrays, sorting, phpunit

I have a big array of 10+ elements.

```
$a = [
    'blue'=>'', 
    'red'=>'', 
    'yellow'=>'', 
    'purple'=>'', 
    'orange'=>'', 
    'white'=>'', 
    'black'=>'', 
    'green'=>'', 
    'brown'=>'',
    'rose'=>'', 
];
```

The order of 3 elements is important to me and only if those elements exist.
In this case,
I need to ensure that 'blue' follows the 'yellow' which follows 'white'. Any or all can be absent.

What to assert to ensure those elements are in proper order?

Comment: Like this: `$this->assertTrue(
array_search("blue",array_keys($a)) < array_search("yellow",array_keys($a)) < array_search("white",array_keys($a))));`  ?

Comment: @Matteo some kind of, but also taking in consideration that some elements can be missing. btw comparisson works only for 2 elements, not 3+

Comment: Should be consecutive?

Comment: You might want to create some kind of interface for this, rather than relying on associative arrays to be in the correct order (if it's that important)

Comment: @RobbieAverill, you mean to convert array to object implementing an interface? but how will you check the order of properties? I think it's possible to check only if properties are filled, not their order...